# Laravel - Get cookie other than root path '/'

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying set and get cookie in Laravel application from different path(other than root '/'). I'm able set the cookie, but when i try to retrieve its failed.

In config/session.php,

```
'path' => base_path(),
```

Anyone please help me to resolve this in Laravel by specifying the Cookie path while retrieve?

Comment: And your code ...?

Comment: In config/session.php,

'path' => base_path(),

Comment: @WhatIf yes tried this and with that i'm able set the cookie and but its not retrieve